# An invalid floating point operation in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a problem with the below code.

```
select security_id
    , cast((exp(sum(log(1+return_base_mkt))))-1 as decimal(32,18)) as YTDReturn
from performance
where REPORT_ID ='Total Fund Asset Class'
and Valuation_Date between '2020.01.01' and '2020.03.31'
group by Security_ID
order by Security_ID
```

Where the error keeps showing up:

> Msg 3623, Level 16, State 1, Line 14
>   An invalid floating point operation occurred.

Can someone please help me?

Comment: (1) Tag with the database you are using.  (2) Provide sample data that shows the problem.  (3) A db or SQL fiddle would be helpful.

Comment: My money is on `log(1+return_base_mkt)`. You can only compute log from non-zero positive numbers. Check that `return_base_mkt` is always > `-1.00`.

Answer (score 0):

Although many things could go wrong, I would guess a `log()` of a negative or zero value.  Does this return anything?

```
select p.*
from performance p
where (1+return_base_mkt) <= 0;
```

Comment: That query does return values. I've tried building a case for when absolute value of log is larger than 1 to be 1, but it didn't work

Comment: @aggieWang . . . In that case, you cannot do what you want -- at least not with the code that you have.  You can filter out the bad values.  Or, if you ask a new question with sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic.